# I'm lost with math operations

Tags: python-3.x

I was solving a python task but I didn't get it quite right, I guess. The task is

> 4.6 Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay. Pay should be the normal rate for hours up to 40 and time-and-a-half for the hourly rate for all hours worked above 40 hours. Put the logic to do the computation of time-and-a-half in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. The function should return a value. Use 45 hours and a rate of 10.50 per hour to test the program (the pay should be 498.75). You should use input to read a string and float() to convert the string to a number. Do not worry about error checking the user input unless you want to - you can assume the user types numbers properly. Do not name your variable sum or use the sum() function.

Here's my code:

```
h = input("Hours?")
r = input("Rate?")
h1 = float(h)
r1 = float(r)
def computepay(h1, r1):
    p = h1 * r1
    return p

if h1 <= 40:
    computepay(h1, r1)
else:
    g = float(h1 - 40)
    g1 = r * 1.5 * g
    pay = computepay(h1, r1) + g1
    print (pay)
input()
```

My output is 551.25
Help me, please. I'm completely lost

Comment: Why do you "guess" you did not get it right? What output do you get, for which input?

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the part

```
pay = computepay(h1, r1) + g1
```

Your are passing the full h1 to the function and not the relevant part 40.0.

```
pay = computepay(40.0, r1) + g1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hrs = input("Enter Hours:")
rate = input("Enter Rate:")
h1 = float(hrs)
r1 = float(rate)

def computepay(h1,r1) :
    p = h1 * r1
    return p

if h1 <= 40 :
    computepay(h1,r1)
else:
    x = (h1 - 40.0)
    y = (r1 * 0.5)
    z = x * y
    pay = computepay(h1, r1) + z

print(pay)
```